# jQuery Sortable SyntaxError: missing name after . operator

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I am following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3mOs0VY_sIw

```
$(function() {
    $( "#navsort" ).sortable({
        update: function(event, ui) {
            var postData = $(this).sortable('serialize');
            console.log(postData);

            $.post('save.php'. {list: postData}, function(o) { // i stuck here giving error
                console.log(o);
            }, 'json');
        }
    });
});
```

I stuck at `$.post('save.php'. {list: postData}, function(o)` and giving error `SyntaxError: missing name after . operator`

Please help me to solve this.. I am new to jquery

Comment: typo here: `'save.php'.` close for too localized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `.` after `save.php` replace it with `,`

```
$.post('save.php', {list: postData}, function(o) { 
                console.log(o);
            }, 'json');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to place a "," after 'save.php' instead of a ".".

```
 $.post('save.php', {list: postData}, function(o) { // i stuck here giving error
                console.log(o);
            }, 'json');
```